# llc: unsupported relocation on symbol

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, relocation, llc, position-independent-code

## Problem

`llc` is giving me the following error:

> LLVM ERROR: unsupported relocation on symbol

## Detailed compilation flow

I am implementing an LLVM frontend for a middle-level IR (MIR) of a compiler, and after I convert various methods to many bitcode files, I link them (`llvm-link`), optimize them (`opt`), convert them to machine code (`llc`), make them a shared library (`clang` for it's linker wrapper), and dynamically load them.
`llc` step fails for some of the methods that I am compiling!

#### Step 1: `llvm-link`: Merge many bitcode files

I may have many functions calling each other, so I `llvm-link` the different bitcode files that might interact with each other. This step has no issues. Example:

`llvm-link function1.bc function2.bc -o lnk.bc`

#### Step 2: `opt`: Run optimization passes

For now I am using the following:

`opt -O3 lnk.bc -o opt.bc`

This step proceeds with no issues, but that's the one that *CAUSES* the problem!
Also, it's necessary because in the future I will need this step to pass extra passes, e.g. `loop-unroll`

#### Step 3: `llc`: Generate machine code (PIC)

I am using the following command:

`llc  -march=thumb -arm-reserve-r9 -mcpu=cortex-a9  -filetype=obj -relocation-model pic opt.bc -o obj.o`

I have kept  the arch specific flags I've set just in case they contribute to the issue. I am using `Position Independent Code` because on next step I will be building a `shared object`.
This command fails with the error I've written on top of this answer.

#### Step 4: `clang`: Generate Shared Object

For the cases that `Step 3` fails, this step isn't reached.
If `llc` succeeds, this step will succeed too!

## Additional information

### Configuration

The following run on an llvm3.6, which runs on an `arm` device.

### Things I've noticed

- If I omit `-O3` (or any other level) with the `opt` step, then `llc` would work.
- If I don't, and instead I omit them from `llc`, `llc` would still fail. Which makes me think that `opt -O<level>` is causing the issue.
- If I use `llc` directly it will work, but I won't be able to run specific passes that `opt` allows me, so this is not a option for me.
- I've faced this issue *ONLY* with 2 functions that I've compiled so far (from their original MIR), which use loops. The others produce working code!
- If I don't use `pic` model at `llc`, it can generate `obj.o`, but then I'll have problems creating an `.so` from it!

### Questions

1. Why is this happening??!!
2. Why `opt` has `-relocation-model` option? Isn't that supposed to be just an `llc` thing? I've tried setting this both at `opt` and `llc` to `pic`, but still fails.
3. I am using `clang` because it has a wrapper to a linker to get the the `.so`. Is there a way to do this step with an LLVM tool instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not use neither llc nor opt. These are developer-side tools that should be never used in any production environment. Instead of this, implement your own proper optimization and codegeneration runtime via LLVM libraries.

As for this particular bug - the thumb codegenerator might contain some bugs. Please reduce the problem and report it. Or don't use Thumb mode at all :)